# Route as modal in Sapper

Tags: routes, svelte, sapper

I am trying to implement in Sapper what is done in the `next.js` example called [with-route-as-modal](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-route-as-modal).

What it does is that when clicking on a link, the new page is shown in a modal instead of replacing the current page, and the URL is updated, reflecting current modal page. It is implemented in several social networks, such as instagram.

In the `next.js` example, it is done by using a dynamic href, like this :

```
<Link href={`/?postId=${id}`} as={`/post/${id}`}>
```

How can I implement it in Sapper ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it in this way :

```js
<script>
  import { prefetch } from '@sapper/app'
  import { onMount, onDestroy } from 'svelte'
  import Post from '../components/Post.svelte'

  let props

  onMount(() => {
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
      if (document.location.pathname === '/about') {
        props = null
      } else {
        const regex = /\/blog\/([\w-]+)/
        if (regex.test(document.location.pathname)) {
          handlePrefetch(document.location.pathname)
        }
      }
    }

    return () => {
      window.onpopstate = null
    }
  })

  function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const clickedHref = event.currentTarget.href
    if (clickedHref === location.href) return

    const pathname = clickedHref.replace(location.origin, '').substring(1)
    history.pushState(null, '', pathname)
    handlePrefetch(pathname)
  }

  async function handlePrefetch(url) {
    const res = await prefetch(url)
    const { branch } = res
    props = branch[1].props.post
  }

  function handleClose() {
    history.pushState(null, '', 'about')
    props = null
  }
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>About</title>
</svelte:head>

<h1>About this site</h1>

<p>This is the 'about' page. There's not much here.</p>

<a href="/blog/what-is-sapper" on:click="{handleClick}">lien ici</a>

{#if props}
<Post title="{props.title}" html="{props.html}"></Post>
<button on:click="{handleClose}"></button>
{/if}
```

I had to handle the pop state event manually (so that back button still works). I then used sapper `prefetch` function and inject resulting props as local props. Then I check if any props are set, and then inject custom HTML depending on it.

The "real page" is just a sapper component that contains `<Post title={post.title} html={post.html} />`